# Saving an image that was drawn onto a bitmap using onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am trying to touch the region of my application to place an AND gate on the screen. So when I touch the AND gate region, and then I touch again to place it on the circuit, the gate gets drawn at the location of my touch, but once I touch again, it goes away.

ive created a circuit statically using canvas.drawBitmap and they appear there and stay. Meaning, ive created a ton of canvas.drawBitmap images that stay on the screen..

```java
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("Debugging", "In onTouchEvent");

        if((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


            placeComponent();
            Touch.horizontalTouched = (int)motionEvent.getX()/ grid.getBlockSize();
            Touch.verticalTouched = (int)motionEvent.getY()/ grid.getBlockSize();
        }

        draw();
        return true;
    }

    void placeComponent(){
        Log.d("Debugging", "In placeComponent");

        // Convert the float screen coordinates
        // into int grid coordinates
        touchTemp = whatWasTouched(Touch.horizontalTouched, Touch.verticalTouched);
    }

    private void regionHit() {
        Bitmap _andTest = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.andgatetrans);

        if(touchTemp.equals("AND")){
            canvas.drawBitmap(_andTest,Touch.horizontalTouched*grid.getBlockSize(),Touch.verticalTouched*grid.getBlockSize(),null);
            //drawIcons.drawANDGatev2(canvas,Touch.horizontalTouched*grid.getBlockSize(),Touch.verticalTouched*grid.getBlockSize());
        }
        if(touchTemp.equals("OR")){
        }
        if(touchTemp.equals("NOT")){
        }
        if(touchTemp.equals("SWITCH")){
        }

    }
    // used to tell regionHit() what to do
    private String whatWasTouched(float horizontalTouched, float verticalTouched) {
        if(horizontalTouched >= 5.0 && horizontalTouched <= 9.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 0.0 && verticalTouched <=4.0){
                return "AND";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 5.0 && horizontalTouched <= 9.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 5.0 && verticalTouched <=9.0){
                return "OR";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 5.0 && horizontalTouched <= 9.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 10.0 && verticalTouched <=14.0){
                return "NOT";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 5.0 && horizontalTouched <= 9.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 15.0 && verticalTouched <=19.0){
                return "SWITCH";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 0.0 && horizontalTouched <= 4.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 0.0 && verticalTouched <=4.0){
                return "Play/Pause";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 0.0 && horizontalTouched <= 4.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 5.0 && verticalTouched <=9.0){
                return "EDIT";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 0.0 && horizontalTouched <= 4.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 10.0 && verticalTouched <=14.0){
                return "WIRE";
            }
        }
        if(horizontalTouched >= 0.0 && horizontalTouched <= 4.0){
            if(verticalTouched >= 15.0 && verticalTouched <=19.0){
                return "LED";
            }
        }

        return "-1";
    }
```

Note: regionTouched() is being called in draw() above onTouchEvent()
I expect to be able to touch the region of my single screen application that indicates "AND" gate, and then touch once more to place it onto the blank part of the canvas and have it stay there and also assign its position on the canvas in which it was placed. But all its doing is being placed and removed once i touch the screen again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your AND gate is selected using whatWasTouched() method and placed in blank part of canvas, on repeating your AND gate disappears and you want it to stay at its position? To accomplish this you need to save position of AND gate somewhere.

In your regionHit() method you are drawing AND gate bitmap.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(_andTest,Touch.horizontalTouched*grid.getBlockSize(),Touch.verticalTouched*grid.getBlockSize(),null);
```

Then on next touch event your whatWasTouched() might not return AND gate and also your Touch class will have updated touch points values. That's why you are not seeing AND gate in next touch.

So you need to save selected gates and also their position on canvas.

Create a class Gate

```
public class Gate {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private int drawX;
    private int drawY;

    public Gate(Bitmap bitmap, int drawX, int drawY) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.drawX = drawX;
        this.drawY = drawY;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c) {
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, drawX, drawY, null);
    }

    public void updateDrawPosition(int drawX, int drawY) {
        this.drawX = drawX;
        this.drawY = drawY;
    }

}
```

And use above class in your view like this

```
public class GatesView extends View {

    private ArrayList<Gate> gates;
    private Bitmap andGateBitmap;

    public GatesView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // bitmap should be decoded here
        andGateBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.andgatetrans);

        final int initialCapacity = 5;
        gates = new ArrayList<>(initialCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // draw all saved gates in the list.
        final int listSize = gates.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
            gates.get(i).draw(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // when a new gate is selected add it to gatesList
        gates.add(new Gate(andGateBitmap, initial Xpos to draw, initial Ypos to draw)); // bitmap should not be decoded from Resource in onDraw() or onTouchEvent().
        invalidate(); // tell android that our view has updated and needs to be redrawn.
        return true;
    }
}
```